# Exception while running XML transformer

Tags: java, xml

I am running test for my code, and after the test report is not generating and giving the below exception.

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Character reference "&#

Comment: Please provide more information about what your application is doing.

Comment: looks like issue with unescaped text, maybe you use not valid XML for testing. or you have encoding issue, look at http://cudou.com/pages/dfihihci-illegal-character-in-xml-are-not-being-replaced.html